# How can I know the bit state in C++ without using bitset?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to know the states of different bits over a char

Let's say I've:

```
char a = 11 //00001011 in binary
```

How can I retrieve bit number 5 which is currently 0 and cast it to a bool variable? And how can I set it?

Comment: In programming I would normally expect you to count bits starting with the rightmost bit being bit zero, so that the nth bit has value 2ⁿ, although you accepted an answer that used 1-based indexing...

Comment: @Neil - A good point to be sure. I'm used to talking with individuals who think of bit positions as 1-8 instead of the 0-7 as they're usually noted in reference manuals. I made that assumption here as well, so I did clarify that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've noted:

```
char a = 11 // == 00001011 in binary
```

Since you said the `bit number 5` is clear right now, let's *define the position of the bits as you're talking about them:

```
pos       8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
value    [0][0][0][0][1][0][1][1]
```

You want to test the 5th bit, that means you need a mask that accesses the fifth bit, here's some masks:

```
your number: 00001011
0x1  mask:   00000001
0x2  mask:   00000010
0x4  mask:   00000100
0x8  mask:   00001000
0x10 mask:   00010000  <-- So that's the one we want, the 5th bit
```

To set your bit you need a bit-wise OR (|)

```
a |= 0x10; //   00001011
           // | 00010000  because 1 | anything = 1
           // ----------
           //   00011011  The value is set!
```

To test the bit we can use the bit-wise AND (&)

```
bool something = a & 0x10; //   00001011
                           // & 00010000  because only 1 & 1 = 1
                           // ----------
                           //   00000000  something will be 0 (false)
```

---

*it was pointed out that this is a  1-based indexing as opposed to the more typical 0-based indexing. Which is true. Based on the description I chose to read the question as "bit number 5" meaning typical (human) based counting of 1, 2, 3, 4, etc out of 8-bits.

If you'd rather use a 0-based indexing, this is no problem, just "shift" the same logic by one, the mask for the "5th" bit in 0-based indexing is `0x20`

When talking about bits it's good to note which is the least significant bit, and 0 or 1 based to be totally clear.

Answer (score 6):

You can use some bitwise operators:

```
bool fifthBitSet = a & 0x10;
```

Or, more generally:

```
bool nThBitSet = a & ( 0x1 << n );
```

Missed the setting part:

```
a |= 0x1 << n; // set n'th bit
```

Comment: He said the fifth bit is zero, so it's definitely not `0x8` however you count it.

Comment: @Neil my bad, I thought he meant from the left.

Answer (score 2):

You can test the bits with bitmasks:

```
a & 0b00010000
```

Answer (score 2):

Counting from 0 being the rightmost bit:

To test it:

```
int b = 5;

bool n = a & (1 << b);
```

To set (or clear) bit `b`:

```
if (n) {  // set
    a |= (1 << b);     // RHS only has bit 'b' set
} else {  // clear
    a &= ~(1 << b);    // RHS has every bit _except_ bit 'b' set
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You mention *bit number 5*, I believe you're looking at the 5th least-significant bit.

You've also asked about how to *set* a bit at a specific position. For that, use bitwise OR - `|`:

```
a = a | 0x10;
```

As has already been answered, test the bit using bitwise AND - `&`:

```
bool isSet = a & 0x10;
```

Often you'll use a positional flag like `0x10`, but the generalizations given using bit-shifts are very useful, especially if you wrap these into a function:

```
int pos = 5;

// set bit 5:
a = a | (0x1 << pos);

// test bit 5:
bool isSet = a & (0x1 << pos);
```

For more information, the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) on bitwise operation is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use this set of functions to get and set the bit states, I suppose:

```
bool getBit(int data, int bitNumber) {
  int flag = 1 << bitNumber - 1;
  return (bool)(data & flag);
}

void setBit(int& data, int bitNumber) {
  int flag = 1 << bitNumber - 1;
  data |= flag;  
}

...
int main() {
  int a = 11;
  cout << getBit(a, 5); // false
  setBit(a, 5);
  cout << getBit(a, 5); // true
}
```

Still I wonder why do you need to use this, and not bitsets. )

Answer (score 0):

You can use bitwise AND to know the states.

```
unsigned int number = 11;
```

AND the number with the value in which the bit position you want to check alone is set and the remaining bits to 0.

Suppose I want to check bit 0, then

```
if(a&0x00000001)
   puts(" 01h bit position   is 1")
else
   puts(" 01h bit position   is 0")
```